# getimagesize / fopen connection refused

Tags: php, apache, fopen, getimagesize

I am trying to get the size from an remote image with the native php function getimagesize from an absolute URL.
I am using PHP 7.3, here is the code:

```
$fichier = 'http://mydomain/images/image.jpg';
$size = getimagesize($fichier);
var_dump($size);
```

And the code return :

```
PHP Warning: getimagesize(http://mydomain/images/image.jpg): failed to open stream: Connection refused in ...
```

And with fopen, same problem:

```
PHP Warning: fopen(http://mydomain/images/image.jpg): failed to open stream: Connection refused
```

And when I am trying the same URL from an other server, it is working.

Also, if I am trying to get infos from an other image and from an other domain but on the same server, it is not working also.

allow_url_fopen is enabled.
I think that it should come from Apache conf, but not sure... Anybody has an idea ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the problem is coming from the network.
Apache could not resolve his own public domain name.
So to correct the problem, I just had " 127.0.0.1 mydomain" in the hosts file, and the problem was solved.
Hope it can help !